# Remove all nodes from an xml except for some

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a simple xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <garbage1>something</garbage1>
    <garbage2>something</garbage2>
    <garbage3>something</garbage3>
    <item>
        <a>
            <b/>
            <c>123</c>
        </a>
        <d>456</d>
    </item>
    <item>
        <a>
            <b/>
            <c>789</c>
        </a>
        <d>666</d>
    </item>
</root>
```

I want to remove all nodes except `<c>` and `<d>` inside the `<item>` nodes to get a result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <c>123</c>
        <d>456</d>
    </item>
    <item>
        <c>789</c>
        <d>666</d>
    </item>
</root>
```

Apparently the right thing to do this is using the identity transformation and then overriding it accordingly. If I just wanted to remove `<c>` and `<d>`, this would do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!--    identity transformation-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--    override identity transformation-->
    <xsl:template match="c|d"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OK, so I just need to negate the argument to get rid of all nodes that are NOT `<c>` or `<d>`. Why does this not work?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!--    identity transformation-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--    override identity transformation to (apparently not) get rid of all nodes except 'c' and 'd'-->
    <xsl:template match="//*[not(local-name() = ('c', 'd'))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you all very much, I feel like missing something simple here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the correct way to accomplish your goal of:

> to remove all nodes except `<c>` and `<d>` inside the `<item>` nodes

is:

**XSLT 1.0/2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor::item][not(self::c or self::d)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This matches any node that is "inside the `<item>`" (i.e. a descendant of `item`) except `c` and `d`, and applies templates to its children, without copying it itself. Thus, for example, the `a` wrapper is removed - but its `c`child is still processed by the *identity transform* template.

---

Your attempt did not work, because your second template was applied to the `root` element. From there, the template did not output anything, nor did it apply any other templates - so the processing ended at that point with an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this with a different approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c | d">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However it still bugs me what is wrong with my original idea, so I'd be very happy if someone can help me there.